# Calculating the best match between two sets

Tags: statistics, absolute-value

I’m a PHP developer and I have a problem calculating the perfect match between two different data sets.

I have data sets from companies, where each company defines the requirements for a specific job. I also have data sets from users, where each user can define a data set describing their skills.

Both of this datasets could hold values between $1$ and $12$.

**Here’s an example of two data sets:**

$\begin{align*}
\text{Company} & \to [\phantom{1}4, \phantom{1}8, 12, \phantom{1}4, 10] \\
\text{User} & \to [\phantom{1}8, 10, \phantom{1}5, \phantom{1}5, \phantom{0}1]
\end{align*}$

**Question:**

What is the best way to calculate the best matching job from a company? There were two thoughts that crossed my mind, but I don’t know which would be better, of if indeed there’s another completely different approach.

1. **Calculate the sum of all absolute diffs.** $\newcommand{\abs}{\operatorname{abs}}$

   For example:
   $$\text{score} = \abs(4-8) + \abs(8-10) + \abs(12-5) + \abs(4-5) + \abs(10-1) = 23$$
2. **Calculate the absolute diff between the sum of both data sets.**

   For example:
   $$\text{score} = \abs\left[(4+8+12+4+10)-(8+10+5+5+1)\right] = 9$$

Comment: This seems like a great candidate for [cosine similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity). Though there are other distance metrics that you could try, so check out the related links.

Comment: This looks very interesting. Checking this out.

Comment: This works very nice! Thanks.

Comment: If you are happy with it (and I am very happy that you are :) .. see smile). Write it up as an answer, and then accept it when you can. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are probably many ways to archive a meaningful solution for this problem. I used the [cosine similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity)

With the example above i get following function:

$\frac{((4*8) + (8*10) + (12*5) + (4*5) + (10*1))} {\sqrt{((4*4) + (8*8) + (12*12) + (4*4) + (10*10))} \times \sqrt{((8*8) + (10*10) + (5*5) + (5*5) + (1*1))}} = 0.74712398867 $

Comment: Try adding edge cases of [1,1,1,1,1] and someother repeated digits. And also very similar and see if it handles your range of data well :).

Comment: @Chinny84, I have added the difference in weighted variance and cosine similarity.  This is in no way disparaging your suggestion.  I would appreciate if you could treat it as a scientific dialogue.  Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @satishramanathan as a data scientist I know that a generally accepted method is not always best (take bag of words approach for example), however, the weights you talk about is parameter of a proposed model and unless the OP requires that I should leave that extra flexibility alone for now. The fact is the differences you have stated should be roughly 0.75 match but due to the extreme value of 12 pushes the cosine similarity score lower to ~0.6 (contd)

Comment: So it still reasonably ok for the problem as stated by the OP. Now if we were to include some weights (which I think is a good idea personally in some cases where you know there is a weighting taking place) then your method is good, though there even better metrics for this scenario as well.

Comment: Also I love scientific debates as that's what scientific method is :).

Comment: @Thanks fo the good spirit. I appreciate your understanding

Comment: @satishramanathan Thanks! What would be the better solution if the different dataset values are in ralation. Say the metrics in company and user are something like 1:php-skills,2:html-skills,3:css-skills and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

One approach could be that you could give weights to each of these skill and find the weighted variance in the sense that in your example,, the five jobs could have been weighted $w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4,w_5$, and let us say for example sake, the weights are 0.2,0.1,0.3,0.15,0.25.

Since it is the best match, we could find the mean of absolute differences, M, ${\sum_{1}^{n} w_i|x_i - x_j|}$

Then find the weighted variance = $\sum_{1}^{i=j} w_i\left(|x_i-x_j| - M)^2\right)$. In your example, M$ = 5.5$

Absolute differences are,$d_1 = 4, d_2 = 2,\cdots, d_5 = 9$

The best matched job could be the least of the following metric(weighted variance): $$\left((0.2).(4-5.5)^2+0.1.(2-5.5)^2+\cdots+0.25.(9-5.5)^2\right) = 8.45$$.

I tried with the following datasets

Company = {3,4,5,8,6}, User = {3,4,5,8,6} = Variance =0 , No change

Company = {4,4,5,8,6}, User = {3,4,5,8,6} = Variance = 0.16, One change

Company = {4,3,5,8,6}, User = {3,4,5,8,6} = Variance = 0.21, Two Changes

Kind of worked for these examples.

You could try this in your job and let me know if it worked to your satisfaction.

[image]

The below table shows the comparison of weighted variance and cosine similarity under two different but similar situations.  The second table has wide difference in company and user rating of the task 1 with weight 0.05 and remainder of the tasks have the same rating. The third table has the same wide difference in company and user rating of the task 4 with weight 0.80 and the remainder of the tasks have the same rating.  Cosine similarity will treat them both the same way while weighted variance will best match the second situation than the third and intuitively it is correct, because the task that mattered most in the second table has no difference and the task that mattered the least had a wide difference thus getting higher priority than the third table where the task that mattered the most had the same difference as that of the task 1 in table 2.  Thus weighted variance gives you additional flexibility in rank ordering similar datasets.

[image]

Thanks

Satish

Comment: This also look very promising but iam not a math specialist. I even cant read the functions. Could you give me an example of how you calculated the weighted variance. Thanks.

Comment: I have added the way to compute the weighted variance in the above table.  Hope it is useful.  Thanks